# How to set up Visual Studio to debug a DLL ("Unable to start program error")

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, visual-studio-2013, vst

Basically, I have a Visual Studio project that builds a DLL (a VST audio plugin).  Where this type of project scenario has been set up for me in the past, I would be able to build, run, and debug the plugin.  Visual studio would automatically launch whichever program I was using to host the plugin. I am trying to achieve the same effect in my current project, but I don't know how to set that up.  Currently when I build and run my DLL in Visual Studio, I get the error "Unable to start program".  The DLL still builds, and I can still run it, but I can't debug it from Visual Studio, because I don't know what I need to do in my project settings to make this happen.  How can I do this?

MORE INFO:

What I do know is that, in projects where this sucessfully works, there are some modifications made to the Visual Studio project settings under fields marked 'pre-build events' and 'post-build events', so presumably what I want to do is edit these in some way to tell Visual Studio the following: "Hey, before you try and run and debug this DLL, you have to launch another program (my program is called Max.exe), and then you have to wait until that program loads the DLL.  Then you can debug!  Don't be a stupid computer and try to debug it before it's even loaded in Max.exe..."

What I do not know : EVERYTHING ELSE.  This is literally all I know about what I'm trying to do, hense the colourful attempt to talk to a computer in English.

Currently when I build and run my DLL in Visual Studio, I get the error "Unable to start program".  This is unsurprising seeing as the project knows nothing about the environment I want to use to test the DLL, but the problem is that I don't have a clue what Visual Studio needs to know.  I really don't know enough about programming to understand the implications of what I'm trying to do either.  Yes, I did mention those fields marked pre-build and post-build because I remember them being important, but I don't know exactly what or how to write in those fields, and I also do not know if there will be more things I need to tell Visual Studio before this will work.

Q.E.D  I'm not actually sure what pre and post build events are, or how they work.  And I barely know the first thing about customizing VS project settings.  All I know is how to write audio processing code.  I felt the need for this disclaimer because typically my questions are met with angry programmers who think I don't do my own research; they fail to realize I am an audio engineer who skipped programming 101.  Yes, how to debug a dll is a common question I'm sure, but answers to those questions tend to assume pre-requisite knowledge that I do not have.

Comment: Go to the Configuration Properties -> Debugging and change the "Command" to the executable that will be loading your DLL.

Comment: Also you can attache to existing process Debug -> Attach to Process

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to edit the Command field in your project's Debugging properties. Right-click on your project in the solution explorer and click Properties (it's generally the last item). Open the Debugging page under Configuration Properties. The Command field indicates which executable to launch when debugging.

By default this contains $(TargetPath) which refers to the final binary your project compiles. This is useless for DLLs since DLLs are not executable. Change this to the path of whatever third party application you are writing a plugin for.

With this change, launching with debugging will actually launch the third party application and attach the debugger to it. Once the application loads your plugin, you will be able to debug it normally.

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio,

1. In `Solution Explorer`, right click on project and select `Properties`.
2. In `Properties`, choose `Configuration Properties -> Debugging`.
3. For `Command`, enter the full path of the executable that will be loading your DLL.  Fill in the `Command Arguments` and `Working Directory` accordingly.

In addition, you need to make sure that the executable actually loads the DLL you are building.  A mistake that a lot make is to launch their executable, and not realize the executable is loading another version of the DLL they are trying to debug.  This can happen due to Windows searching for the first DLL that it finds using the DLL searching logic (exe directory, path, etc.).